# Type-Ahead Datalist Textbox Not Resetting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have an app that contains a type-ahead textbox. The users wanted the type-ahead to use "Starts With" instead of "Contains" for the search. My colleague wrote some javascript to enable the "Starts With" search. It works great...until I click the Add button. Then the list does not refresh with all of the options. Here is what I mean:
The textbox/datalist begins (on loading/refreshing the page) populated as follows:
Apple
Apricot
Avocado
Banana
Blackberry
Blueberry
Cherry
Coconut
Cranberry

If I begin typing C, the textbox/datalist now contains:
Cherry
Coconut
Cranberry

If I select Cherry and then click Add, I would expect the list to return to its original state with all of the fruit, however it retains the value of Cherry and deleting Cherry only adds back the other fruits that start with "C," so the list is once again:
Cherry
Coconut
Cranberry

I need all of the fruit back in the list after an add. Please see the following code:
From the aspx:

```
<datalist id="dlParentFruit">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phParentFruit" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</datalist>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddStdFruit" list="dlParentFruit" runat="server" Width="200px" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fteAddFruit" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAddStdFruit" FilterType="Custom" FilterMode="InvalidChars" InvalidChars="&quot;'[]{}\|^~`!@#$"></ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlValAddFruit" runat="server" CssClass="cse-val-tooltip cse-hide">
    <img src="../Images/triangle.png" alt="validation error" />
    <ul id="vulAddFruit" runat="server"></ul>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddStdFruit" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Required: Fruit"
    ControlToValidate="txtAddStdFruit"
    Display="None"
    ValidationGroup="Add"
    data-val="pnlValAddFruit">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The code behind (VB):
```
Private Sub btnAddStdFruit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddStdFruit.Click
    Try
        If IsErrorShownForAdd Then
            ResetAddValidation()
        End If

```
    Page.Validate("Add")

    If IsAddValid() Then

        Dim dateMin As DateTime = Me.StdDate & " " & Helper.SetTime(txtAddStart.Text)
        Dim dateMax As DateTime
        If txtAddStop.Text = 2400 Then
            dateMax = Helper.setMidnight(Me.StdDate, txtAddStop.Text)
        Else
            dateMax = Me.StdDate & " " & Helper.SetTime(txtAddStop.Text)
        End If

        Dim itemSelected As New ListItem
        Dim ctrAddedFrts As Integer = 0
        Dim bolDupeRow As Boolean = False

        Dim strResourceList As String = String.Empty

        For Each itemSelected In lbLocationResource.Items
            If itemSelected.Selected = True Then

                bolDupeRow = IsFruitDuplicate(-1, itemSelected.Text, dateMin, dateMax, txtAddStdFruit.Text, ddlAddCategory.SelectedValue)

                If bolDupeRow = False Then
                    MRData.AddStdFruit(Me.StdID, txtAddStdFruit.Text, itemSelected.Value, dateMin, dateMax, ddlAddCategory.SelectedValue, Me.UserID, "Edit All Frt - Added Fruit")
                    ctrAddedFrts += 1
                End If
                strResourceList = strResourceList & itemSelected.Value & ","
            End If
        Next

        If strResourceList.Length > 0 Then
            'Remove last comma
            strResourceList = strResourceList.Substring(0, strResourceList.Length - 1)
            Me.SelectedResourceList = strResourceList
        End If


        If ctrAddedFrts > 0 Then

            txtAddStart.Text = String.Empty
            txtAddStop.Text = String.Empty
            pnlValAddLocation.CssClass = Constants.VALIDATOR_PANEL_RESET_STYLE

            ResetStdRequestSet()
            ResetMenuFruitList()
            ResetStandardFruitList()

            BindLists()
            BindStdFruits()


        ElseIf ctrAddedFrts = 0 AndAlso bolDupeRow = False Then
            IsErrorShownForAdd = True
            pnlValAddLocation.CssClass = Constants.VALIDATOR_PANEL_STYLE
            lbLocationResource.CssClass = "cse-select-error"

            Dim listItem As New HtmlGenericControl("li")
            listItem.InnerHtml = Helper.FormatErrorMessage("Error: Location must be chosen")
            vulAddLocation.Controls.Add(listItem)


        ElseIf ctrAddedFrts = 0 AndAlso bolDupeRow = True Then
            IsErrorShownForAdd = True
            pnlValAddLocation.CssClass = Constants.VALIDATOR_PANEL_STYLE
            lbLocationResource.CssClass = "cse-select-error"

            Dim listItem As New HtmlGenericControl("li")
            listItem.InnerHtml = Helper.FormatErrorMessage("Error: Duplicate Fruit")
            vulAddLocation.Controls.Add(listItem)
        End If

    End If

    pnlAddStdFruits.Attributes.Add("style", "display: New;")
    hlAddFruits.InnerText = "-Add Fruits"

    upnlStdFruits.Update()

Catch ex As Exception
    AppUtilities.HandleError(ex, Me.Page, Identity.SystemUserID, Constants.SITE_ID, PAGE_NAME)
End Try
```

End Sub

Sub BindLists()
ddlAddCategory.DataSource = Me.FruitCategoryList
ddlAddCategory.DataTextField = "Fruit_CATEGORY"
ddlAddCategory.DataValueField = "Fruit_CATEGORY_ID"
ddlAddCategory.DataBind()
ddlAddCategory.Items.Insert(0, New WebControls.ListItem("", -1))
ddlAddCategory.SelectedIndex = 0

```
phParentFruit.Controls.Clear()


Dim dtFruits As DataTable = Me.StandardFruitList

Dim hgcParentList As New HtmlGenericControl
hgcParentList.InnerHtml = Helper.BuildDatalist(dtFruits, "Fruit_TEXT", "LU_ID_CAT")
phParentFruit.Controls.Add(hgcParentList)
```

End Sub

Public Sub BindStdFruits(Optional ByVal dt As DataTable = Nothing)
Dim dtStdFrt As DataTable
If Me.MenuFruitList Is Nothing Then
ResetMenuFruitList()
dtStdFrt = Me.MenuFruitList
Else
dtStdFrt = Me.MenuFruitList
End If

```
If Me.StandardFruitList Is Nothing Then
    ResetStandardFruitList()
End If

If dtStdFrts.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    gvStdFrt.DataSource = dtStdFrt
    gvStdFrt.DataBind()

    lblGridMessage.Text = String.Empty
    lblGridMessage.Visible = False

    If Not Me.IsReadOnly Then
        hlMassTime.Visible = True
        btnDelete.Visible = True
        btnUpdate.Visible = True
    Else
        hlMassTime.Visible = False
        btnDelete.Visible = False
        btnUpdate.Visible = False
    End If

    gvStdFrt.Visible = True
Else
    lblGridMessage.Visible = True
    lblGridMessage.Text = "No menu Fruits"

    If (hlAddFruits.Visible = True) Then
        pnlAddStdFruits.Attributes.Add("style", "display: New;")
        hlAddFruits.InnerText = "-Add Fruits"
    End If

    btnDelete.Visible = False
    btnUpdate.Visible = False
    hlMassTime.Visible = False
    gvStdFrt.Visible = False
End If

upnlStdFruits.Update()
```

End Sub

Sub ResetStandardFruitList()
Dim dtStdFrt As DataTable
dtStdFrt = MIMData.GetStandardFruitByType("STD")
Me.StandardFruitList = dtStdStdFrt
End Sub

```
<br />
JavaScript:<br />
```

Methods.addNewFruitsFruitListStartsWith = function (txtFruit) {

```
if (typeof txtFruit !== 'undefined' && txtFruit !== null && txtFruit.nodeName === 'INPUT' &&
    Controls.addPanelFruitOptions !== null && typeof Controls.addPanelFruitOptions !== 'undefined' &&
    Inputs.initialAddPanelFruitDataListContent !== null && typeof Inputs.initialAddPanelFruitDataListContent !== 'undefined') {

    var value = txtFruit.value;

    if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== '') {
        var options = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < Controls.addPanelFruitOptions.length; i++) {
            if (Controls.addPanelFruitOptions[i].value.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())) {
                options += '<option value="' + Controls.addPanelFruitOptions[i].value + '" />';
            }
        }

        Controls.addPanelFruitDataList.innerHTML = options;
    } else {
        Controls.addPanelFruitDataList.innerHTML = Inputs.initialAddPanelFruitDataListContent;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the `.aspx`, I had to move the `DataList` control to the `UpdatePanel`. Silly mistake!